# How can I add a button in my android app that posts the picture which is in image view to a Facebook page?

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

How can I add a button in my android app that posts the picture which is in image view only to face book page?

this button here shares the image to all media which is not the requirement.
here `init` is the method which is performing the task.

Here is what i was trying:

```
`private void init(){


    File dir = new File("/sdcard/Testing/");
    try {
        if (dir.mkdir()) {
            System.out.println("Directoryted");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Directoryot created");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_click:
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,CAMERA_REQUEST);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_share:
            Bitmap bitmap1 = loadBitmapFromView(relativeLayout, relativeLayout.getWidth(), relativeLayout.getHeight());
            saveBitmap(bitmap1);
            String str_screenshot = "/sdcard/Testing/" + "testing" + ".jpg";

            fn_share(str_screenshot);
            break;

    }

}

public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    File imagePath = new File("/sdcard/Testing/" + "testing" + ".jpg");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

        Log.e("ImageSave", "Saveimage");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        image.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
}

public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v, int width, int height) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.draw(c);

    return b;
}

public void fn_share(String path) {

    File file = new File("/mnt/" + path);

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image"));

}`
```

Comment: here the button with id 'btn_share' is performing the shearing

Answer (score 0):

You can use facebook share sdk https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Comment: can it also be done with the help of implicit intent

Comment: i wouldn't recommend it but you could use 'intent.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");' or 'intent.setPackage("com.facebook.lite");' but only one could be used at a time. You may want to use PackageManager to see if the apps are installed, but from a security point setPackage is not secure, because any app can use facebook, WhatsApp, Instagram ... packages if they're not already installed.Hope this helps

Comment: yes i have downloaded the SDK from the link provided above and i am working on it

Comment: If your query is resolved do green tick the answer :)